# Using HTTP Client for Places API in golang, Unmarshall JSON and invalid characters

Tags: json, http, go

I am pretty new to Go, learning how to use it. Wanted to test hitting the Google Places API, but am having some trouble in writing the request. It seems the request goes through, I receive something in the body, but I cannot Unmarshall it. I just want to see the json printed in string form so I can try to decode it. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
type place struct {
    Name string `json:candidates`
}

func main() {
    places("Grill")
}

func places(inputText string) {
url := "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/"

placesClient := http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Testing how to query API's from parameters")
q := req.URL.Query()
q.Add("key", PLACES_KEY)
q.Add("input", inputText)
q.Add("inputtype", "textquery")
req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
pln(req.URL.String())

res, getErr := placesClient.Do(req)
if getErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(getErr)
}

body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if readErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(readErr)
}

output := place{}
jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &output)
if jsonErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(jsonErr)
}

pln(output)
}
```

Comment: "I cannot Unmarshall it" - why? What happens? Please post any error(s) you get and the invalid response body you received.

Comment: If you just want to see the response so you can decode it, then you can use `fmt.Println(string(body))`.  However, I would say that the output of `log.Fatal(jsonErr)` should be providing the information that you need to fix the problem, likely that the `place` type, or one(all) of its fields is not exported.

Comment: I realized the issue, I wasn't receiving JSON at all since the url was incorrect. thank you @threeve for the string(body) recommendation that helped me realize the mistake, it's working now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the help, ended up finding the answer. The issue was partly with my understanding of the Places API, I had entered `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/` but need to make sure to put `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json` The JSON part at the end specifies the return type, otherwise my body was constantly getting 404 errors. This can be fixed by adding:

```
if res.StatusCode == 404 {
    log.Fatal("Hit a 404")
}
```

Also, if you just want to print out the byte string, this worked for me

```
n := len(body)
s := string(body[:n])

pln(s)
```

this allows you to see what is being printed easier